# Casting Double object to int

Tags: java, casting, int, double

How can I convert from a Double object to an int? The following code works but seems slightly unconventional (with casting twice):

```
Double d = new Double(4.0);
int i = (int)(double)d;
```

When I try `int i = (int)d`, I get an error from Eclipse (`Cannot cast from Double to int`), which makes sense. Nevertheless, is there a simpler way of converting a Double object to an int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Double.intValue()
```

is the provided method that does that conversion.

Comment: Thanks, will accept in 7 minutes when I can. Also, out of curiosity, is there such thing as `Integer.charValue()`? I have seen byteValue, shortValue, intValue, longValue, floatValue, and doubleValue for the Integer object, but no charValue.

Comment: @Kootling You should ask a different question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast double to int you will loss decimal value.. so 4.99 double become 4 int. If still want to convert than try-

int i = d.intValue();

Answer (score 0):

In your case you use

```
Double.intValue()
```

as a method to convert the Double Object to Integer.